# vectorizing halftone/newsprint object

Tags: vector

I'm tryin to make this thickening halftone effect

I got here a simple example of a circle with a gradient from black to white

[image]

and I did the following effect with gimp
[image]

only problem is that I need it as a vector which means I have to use image trace which I'm not a big fan of.

Does somebody know a way hoy can I get that effect ready as a vector?
I saw some plugins that may do the job but I'm a bit short on budget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in Inkscape (which is free).

1. Using the Bézier tool set "Triangle in" as the shape, draw a line, and adjust the triangle until it's the shape you want.
2. Copy it, paste in place, and move it down
3. Select all, and run the Interopolate extension, set as many steps as required
4. Create a circle, copy it
5. Select interpolated strokes + circle
6. Set the circle as a clipping path
7. Paste in place to bring back the circle.
8. Select all and group

[image]

Comment: Well, I gave a circle with a simple gradient as a simple example, the problem starts when I try to make a more complex image

Comment: @tristramit You can use any shape you want as a clipping path in Inkscape - it's not only limited to circles, and the fill can contain anything you want too. Inkscape is capable of very complex images.

Comment: @tristramit - or perhaps you meant to ask a different question.  Like "How can I use GIMP to create vector images?".  The answer is, you can't.  It's a raster image editor. Apart from auto-tracing or manually recreating a vector image, there's no way to automatically turn a raster image into vector.